# Export two separate dataframes, as csv, to two separate fixed file names but with variable paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyqt5, export-to-csv

I read, manipulate and now want to export two separate dataframes to .csv.
I us QtWidget to select the path.

For my Export I have:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
export_file_path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, "Select File", "", "Line Files (*.csv)")   
df_Sum.to_csv(export_file_path,index=False) 
export_file_path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, "Select File", "", "Line Files (*.csv)")  
df_QC.to_csv(export_file_path,index=False)
```

This works, but seems a basic way of doing it. I'd like to choose the `export_file_path` once and then use the path for both files using a fixed file name for each, e.g. export_file_path"df_Sum.csv" and export_file_path"df_QC.csv"

Comment: Use `QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory` and then write the files within that.

Comment: every GUI has dialog to select Folder/Directory. Eventually you should remove filename from `export_file_path` and keep only directory  - i.e. `os.path.dirname(...)` - and use it two times (without running second `getSaveFileName`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory` suggested in Comment 1 worked well, but I then realised if I was writing to the same directory as I had opened the initial file from, I could use Comment 2's suggestion and strip the directory path from the open file dialog as save myself a step.

```
import_file, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select File", "", "Line Files (*.csv)") # Ask for file
##Do some stuff and make 2 dataframes

#Save both
Export_Directory=os.path.dirname(import_file) #Get path name from import_file path
Sum_Name='QC_Summary.csv'
QC_Name='QC_Log.csv'
Complete_Sum=os.path.join(Export_Directory,Sum_Name)
Complete_Log=os.path.join(Export_Directory,QC_Name)
df_Sum.to_csv(Complete_Sum,index=False)
df_QC.to_csv(Complete_Log,index=False)
```